# How to set capacity for Java DelayQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, java.util.concurrent

I was using `LinkedBlockingQueue` queue to implement `producer-consumer pattern` for TCP/IP events transfer, I was using `boolean offer(e)` which means once the queue is reach its capacity, the new incoming events will be ignored(dropped) and it returns `false`.

Now I have to hold the events for a configurable time(say 2 seconds), so I decided to use `DelayQueue` which can hold elements and release elements only when time expired.

Unfortunately, `DelayQueue` is **unbounded**. I am wondering whether there's a way to set a capacity for `DelayQueue` or  `delayQueue.size() == CAPACITY` is always reliable?

Comment: When the queue is full, do you want to wait until space is available and then add to the queue? What is the delay for?

Comment: the delay has nothing to do with the queue capacity, an element can only be taken out of queue when time expired.  The purpose to check queue is full is I want to count the number of events which are dropped.

Comment: You could check the size() before adding or sub-class the DelayQueue to make offer() do this.

Comment: @haifzhan I'm sorry. I was referring to the first queue. And why you would need a delay if that queue is full.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is size() thread safe? What If I have  multiple threads  insert into DelayQueue and take out from the same queue, is the number returned from size() still reliable?

Comment: @haifzhan there is a risk that you will have multiple threads think they can add an element and the queue goes over the size temporarily. It depends on how critical it it to not have one or two extra elements.

Comment: @haifzhan `size()` can be considered thread safe in all ... `java.util.concurrent` classes.

Comment: ..if you need "a capacity" you should extend DelayQueue, and care for its (capacities) thread safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sizeable problem since we need access to the internal lock used by DelayQueue if we were to subclass it or delegate to it and the lock is private in DelayQueue.

We can't use a second lock because that would cause issues with `take`. You could maybe implement that yourself, but doing that you're more than halfway to your own implementation of DelayQueue so that probably isn't what you want.

We can access the lock using reflection. Note however that this isn't the best of ideas since it relies on implementation details of DelayQueue. It might not work on all JREs and might even break if you change the version of the JRE you're running on. That said, I think it's the absolute simplest solution to your problem, albeit a bit dirty.

```
/**
 * Bounded implementation of {@link DelayQueue}. This implementation uses
 * reflection to access the internal lock in {@link DelayQueue} so might
 * only work on the Oracle 1.8 JRE.
 * @param <T>
 */
public class BoundedDelayQueue<T extends Delayed> extends DelayQueue<T> {

    // Lock used to synchronize every operation
    private final transient ReentrantLock lock;

    // The limit
    private final int limit;

    BoundedDelayQueue(int limit) {
        try {
            // Grab the private lock in DelayQueue using reflection so we can use it
            // to gain exclusive access outside of DelayQueue
            Field lockField = DelayQueue.class.getDeclaredField("lock");
            lockField.setAccessible(true);
            this.lock = (ReentrantLock) lockField.get(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new Error("Could not access lock field", e);
        }
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    // All the various ways of adding items in DelayQueue delegate to
    // offer, so we only have to override it and not the other methods
    public boolean offer(final T t) {
        // Lock the lock
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // Check the size limit
            if(size() == limit) {
                return false;
            }
            // Forward to superclass
            return super.offer(t);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't implement `offer` with a timeout, if you need that you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  why use reflection? the instance of BoundedDelayQueue will be shared with multi-threads, I am trying to initialize a lock inside BoundedDelayQueue class and lock/unlock in the `offer(boolean)` method, is it thread safe, is the lock here static or non-static will affect thread safe? Thanks:)

Comment: We have to use reflection because we need the exact same lock that the DelayQueue is using and the only way of accessing it is via reflection. If we use a separate lock we'd have to override and reimplement all methods that needs to be synchronized - and at that point we might just as well be reimplementing DelayQueue from the ground up because that's essentially what we'd be doing.

Comment: The lock here is not static and it's the exact same as is used by DelayQueue so it's thread safe.